# OKHTTP -- Posting user-input data, retrieving JSON response to determine success

Tags: java, php, json, http, okhttp

I've been thinking in how to do this. I've read trough the OKHTTP documentation, I have an idea on how to handle this but I'm not entirely sure.

I'll have the user submit three fields ( Username, Password, Database ). I'll have a PHP file uploaded to my host which accepts post data. ( It's pure PHP, so no html. It just accepts data posted to the page. )

Once the values have been submitted, i'll perform a check. Credentials found? Return/echo  JSON array ( Success/ Failure ). I could check if the array key " success " equals either 1 || 0. If 1, show a toast that user has been logged in successfully.

Now, as for the question. Is my logic correct? If not, how would you do it? Do you have any tips for me? Any examples?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Shoud be quite simple to do http `post` with OkHttp, and read the value from JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the "authorization" in HTTP requests you have to set the header to 403.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');

echo 'You are forbidden!';
```

But when I send JSON via a PHP page, I am using a 'generator' to make it easy, like [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP).

```
include('includes/json.php');

$json = new json();

$json->add('status', '403');
$json->add('message', 'YOU ARE FORBIDDEN!');

$json->send();
```

UPDATE : Headers if you want to send "home made" JSON :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

EDIT :

There is also the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), I didn't try it, but it seems very efficient! [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) is as the name says, just to create a JSON & send it, it do not use make use of routes at all.

Comment: Couldn't I simply return a self-made JSON array? Instead of doing that ^^? I can't seem to understand your response :( What am i achieving with that?

Could you give me an example for my situation? Would i have to receive/read the JSON response differently with okhttp?

Comment: You can return self made JSON, without using the HTTP status. But don't forget to set the correct headers for the JSON!